# video.load() does not work on ios10 on chrome

Tags: javascript, html, ios

I have this following html page:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <video controls>
    </video>

    <script>
       window.onload = function () {
           var video = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
           video.addEventListener("canplay", function(){
              alert("canplay");
           });
           video.setAttribute("src", "http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4");
           video.load();
       };
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, I am running this page on an iphone with iOS 10.
On safari - the alert "canplay" is called just fine.
On chrome - the alert is not called.

I will also mention that this is something new on iOS 10. on iOS 9 it worked just fine on both browsers.

Does anybody know why does this happen, and how do I work around this issue?

Thanks.